# Any available methods to speedup cvxpy scs solver?

Tags: python, performance, cvxpy, linear-equation

I meet a problem with the speedup `cvxpy` solve method(basically use SCS solver)，the task contains lots of constraints and a big matrix. I have tried the following methods:

1. use `mkl` `blas` & `lapack` library to replace the original library. (got a little improvement)
2. use GPU and `scs` to do matrix calculation. (made a worse performance)
3. update to the latest python and the corresponding library. (got a little improvement)

those solutions didn't improve the performance enough(even the GPU indirect calculation get a worse result), Did anybody has some advice about this project.

Comment: You my want to try out another optimizer like Mosek.

Comment: tks a lot, `mosek` do save my time.

Comment: A bit curious about how much faster?

Comment: in our situation(SOCP problem), `mosek` speedup about 2~10x compared with scs.

Comment: Thanks. Btw Mosek should produce a more accurate solution too.